# How to make RMarkdown (.Rmd) table captions go at the top

Tags: r, pandoc, r-markdown

Usually tables have captions at the top.

However, RMarkdown always places the caption at the bottom for pdf_document outputs:

[image]

This is strange because in html docs the caption is automatically placed at the top:

[image]

How do I make table captions go to the top in the pdf documents also?

Reproducible example (replace pdf_document with html_document to see both) - the contents of my file tables.Rmd:

```
---
title: "tables"
author: "Robin Lovelace"
date: "09/16/2014"
output: pdf_document
---

text...

Table: This is a table

| id| age|sex | zone|
|--:|---:|:---|----:|
|  1|  59|m   |    2|
|  2|  54|m   |    2|
|  4|  73|f   |    2|

text...

| id| age|sex | zone|
|--:|---:|:---|----:|
|  1|  59|m   |    2|
|  2|  54|m   |    2|
|  4|  73|f   |    2|

Table: This is a table

texts...
```

Comment: For *pdf*, you might use the `floatrow` (LaTeX) package with `\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}`

Comment: Thanks for this comment @daroczig. I can see how this would work after the `keep_tex: true` option in latex, but unsure about how to implement this solution in RMarkdown. Putting `\usepackage{floatrow}` in the yaml preamble, for example, does not work...

Comment: You have to add that line (and the `usepackage` directive) to the LaTeX preamble, not in YAML. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194569/2878

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - `in_header:` makes so many things possible. However, I've placed this in mystyle.sty: `\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}` and the problem persists...

Answer (score 8):

[This thread can shed some light on the problem you're having](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/138). **Note that the latest version of pandoc (1.13.2) now places table captions on top in pdf output.**

The following examples are with **pandoc-1.12.3**

Unfortunately the `\usepackage{floatrow}` suggestion doesn't work for `longtable` (the table environment generated by the [LaTeX writer for pandoc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.13.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Writers-LaTeX.html)), because it is not a `float` environment.

```
---
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
output: pdf_document
---

| id| age|sex | zone|
|--:|---:|:---|----:|
|  1|  59|m   |    2|
|  2|  54|m   |    2|
|  4|  73|f   |    2|

Table: This is a table
```

This table produces the following latex:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}rrlr@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
id & age & sex & zone
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
1 & 59 & m & 2
\\\addlinespace
2 & 54 & m & 2
\\\addlinespace
4 & 73 & f & 2
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\caption{This is a table}
\end{longtable}
```

Which makes the table you described -- the caption does not respond to the `\floatsetup` in the yaml header).

[image: table 1]

To place the caption at the top, `\caption{}` can be moved. I don't personally know an easy way to force a `longtable` caption to the top (but I'm not a LaTeX expert).

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}rrlr@{}}
\caption{This is a table} \\
\toprule\addlinespace
id & age & sex & zone
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
1 & 59 & m & 2
\\\addlinespace
2 & 54 & m & 2
\\\addlinespace
4 & 73 & f & 2
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

[image: table 2]

You can use the `xtable` package to generate tables that are in a `table` environment that responds to the `\floatsetup` in the preamble (though the package also gives you the option to place the caption at the top).

````
```{r results = 'asis'}
library(xtable)
# Preset some options for printing your xtables
options(xtable.caption.placement = 'bottom', # notice \floatsetup overrides
        xtable.include.rownames = FALSE,
        xtable.comment = FALSE,
        xtable.booktabs = TRUE)

xtable(
  data.frame(
    id = c(1L, 2L, 4L),
    age = c(59L, 54L, 73L),
    sex = c('m', 'm', 'f'),
    zone = rep(2L, 3)),
  caption = 'This is a table')
```
````

[image: table 3]

The caveat to all of this is that all of the raw LaTeX that is fed to pandoc will be removed if you decide to compile to html... bummer.